# What is hostname for my first deployment in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using an ElasticSearch (`elasticsearch==7.0.2`) client in Python

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

client = Elasticsearch({
  "host": "https://my-first-deployment.es.southamerica-east1.gcp.elastic-cloud.com", 
  "port": 9200
})
```

I took the hostname from my first deployment in ElasticSearch, Copy Endpoint:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work

```py
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I don't know what port it should be and I don't know where to check it. I assumed it is 9200 because it is the default port when running locally.

Comment: Are you sure the port in this endpoint is indeed 9200 and not some other random looking number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure your port is incorrect and you should probably remove `https://` from the host name, put it into an array and somehow indicated that it should use ssl. I think it might be much easier to just use the entire endpoint in this format:

```py
client = Elasticsearch(["https://my-first-deployment.es.southamerica-east1.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:12345"],
    http_auth=("elastic", "<password>"),
)
```

Alternatively, you can just copy cluster id and use it like this:

```py
es = Elasticsearch(
    cloud_id="cluster-1:dXMa5Fx...",
    http_auth=("elastic", "<password>"),
)
```

Note: I'm assuming your username is `elastic`.

Also, what's your deployment version? If it is 8.x you should probably switch to corresponding version of python client.

Comment: My deployment version is `v8.10.3`. I will update `elasticsearch`.

Comment: in case you want to answer another easy question, I don't know how to find `cluster-1`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77329016/how-to-know-the-cluster-number-in-elasticsearch. Anyway, I plugged in `cluster-1:..` and it works now, thx

Comment: I think you replaced () with {} in that question.

Comment: yes, but I replaced it now back and it doesn't change the result

Comment: Now I got this UTF8 decode error https://stackoverflow.com/q/77329359/7769052