# How to know the cluster number in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77327613/7769052, in the code

```py
es = Elasticsearch(
    cloud_id="cluster-1:dXMa5Fx...",
    http_auth=("elastic", "<password>"),
)
```

there is `cluster-1` in the first part of the cloud ID, however when I copied the cluster ID from my first deployment, I only got the second part

[image]

and that's what I plugged into my code

```py
client = Elasticsearch(
    cloud_id="dXMa5Fx...", 
    http_auth={"elastic", "<password>"}
)
```

but when I ran it, I got the error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/main.py", line 142, in <module>
http_auth={"elastic", "dXMa5Fx..."}
...
cluster_name, cloud_id = cloud_id.split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

It's strange it told about the line 142, not 141, but whatever, I think it's cloud ID and the cluster, but I don't know the cluster number and I don't know where to look for it in the Elastic Search interface. How to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud ID is actually here, I copied the wrong thing

[image: cloud id in my first deployment]