# ElasticSearch cloud-ID UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using an ElasticSearch (`elasticsearch==8.10.1`) client in Python

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

client = Elasticsearch(
    cloud_id="cluster-1:df45130c5b1843248d0da0c57ac614bf", 
    http_auth=("elastic", "23R9rstnif092SIOO02KKARST")
)
```

but I got the error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/main.py", line 142, in <module>
    http_auth=("elastic", "23R9rstnif092SIOO02KKARST")
File "/home/kamil/anaconda3/envs/elasticsearch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.transport = transport_class(_normalize_hosts(hosts), **kwargs)
File "/home/kamil/anaconda3/envs/elasticsearch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.set_connections(hosts)
File "/home/kamil/anaconda3/envs/elasticsearch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 177, in set_connections
    connections = list(zip(connections, hosts))
File "/home/kamil/anaconda3/envs/elasticsearch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 173, in _create_connection
    return self.connection_class(**kwargs)
File "/home/kamil/anaconda3/envs/elasticsearch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in __init__
    decodestring(cloud_id.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8").split("$")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually didn't update the elasticsearch version correctly. I should have used

```
pip install elasticsearch==8.10.1
```